# Single word or phrase alternative to a "tongue poke"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, adjectives

I am looking for a single word or phrase alternative to a tongue poke, whether that's another expression or gesture or an adjective which describes a show of the same feeling.

The feeling I am trying to get across is the mild/friendly annoyance, disbelief and teasing as a reaction to something someone has said or done. Eg. Friend A is trying to say something sincere and Friend B makes a sarcastic or snide remark, teasing them, making Friend A reacts by teasing them back with a single expression, gesture or action. Verbally Friend A would be reacting with something like "oh dear" or "did you really just say that?".

Looking forward to your suggestions. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You’ve got it already—*tease* as a verb or noun, and its synonyms. I happen to like *needle* in the  circumstances described in the question, but that’s a personal preference and a matter of style.

From https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tease#synonyms

> Synonyms for tease
> Synonyms: Verb
> chaff, jive, joke, josh, kid, rally, razz, rib, ride, roast
> Synonyms: Noun
> baiter, harasser, heckler, mocker, needler, persecutor, quiz, quizzer, ridiculer, taunter, teaser, tormentor (also tormenter), torturer